# asp telerik treeView throws an exception when trying to renderControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, telerik, stringwriter

I am working on a TreeView and have to execute the renderControl() method.  When it fires, it gives an exception:  InvalidOperationException: Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.

I have the following code when will comment where the error is:

```
try{
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter tOut = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
   ddFieldFilter.RenderControl(tOut);  //This doesnt error.
   tvFields = new RadTreeView();
   tvFields.NodeExpand += new RadTreeViewEventHandler(tvFields_NodeExpand);
   tvFields.NodeClick += new RadTreeViewEventHandler(tvFields_NodeClick);
   startTree();
   tvFields.RenderControl(tOut);  //Errors here.
   String context = writer.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
   throw new Exception("Error Loading Page: " + e.Message);
}
```

Do you think it might be because there is currently content in the writer?  I was thinking to clear or flush it to the string and then rebuild it.  I wasnt sure it would append onto the current buffer

**Let me know if you need additional Information**

Comment: Where in your page is this code being executed?

Comment: What i was going to do is take the control and .toString() it to get the markup and then pass the markup to a client machine.  Then on the client, reconstruct the client/server connection

Comment: it is executed in a webservice method, which builds it all serverside and then pushes the markup to the client.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is supported. See [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/page-cannot-be-null-please-ensure-that-this-operation-is-being-performed-in-the-context-of-an-asp-net-request.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will find a different way to accomplish the tasks.  If you put that as the answer, i will accept it.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't look like it is currently supported. Although this question is in regards to the Asp.NET `ColorPicker` control, I believe it applies to the `RadTreeView` control as well.

Via the [Telerik Support Center](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/page-cannot-be-null-please-ensure-that-this-operation-is-being-performed-in-the-context-of-an-asp-net-request.aspx):

> Q:
>   Is there any way to get the ColorPicker to render without a page? I
>   had to add it in a situation where I write directly in the aspx, not
>   aspx.cs. Also, I might need to do it from a generic handler, ashx. Is
>   this possible?
>
> A: 
>   The control needs to be added to a page, either in its markup, or in
>   its code-behind. You could try the RenderControl method and write to
>   Response.OutputStream, yet this is not a supported scenario and it
>   success cannot be guaranteed, so I advise against such attempts.
>
> Regards,
>   Marin
>   the Telerik team